# computed object property giving different result than dot notation

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, properties

I'm using a merge sort function. When I use the dot notation for the property I'm trying to use, it sorts them properly. I decided I wanted to be able to reuse the sort functionality on other properties, so I decided to make the property an argument in the function instead of it being hard coded. The problem is when I passed it the same property the items sorted differently. Not sure why this is happening.

Here is the array of objects that I'm sorting based on the "points" property.

```
[ { teamNum: 0, points: 2, GD: -2, goals: 3, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 1, points: 2, GD: -2, goals: 3, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 2, points: 1, GD: -3, goals: 2, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 3, points: 4, GD: 1, goals: 4, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 4, points: 5, GD: 4, goals: 5, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 5, points: 4, GD: 2, goals: 6, rank: 0 } ]
```

working merge-sort function:

*notice the **.points** in the *if* statement of merge

```
  function mergeSort(arr){
   var len = arr.length;
   if(len <2)
      return arr;
   var mid = Math.floor(len/2),
       left = arr.slice(0,mid),
       right =arr.slice(mid);
   //send left and right to the mergeSort to break it down into pieces
   //then merge those
   return merge(mergeSort(left),mergeSort(right));
}


function merge(left, right){
  var result = [],
      lLen = left.length,
      rLen = right.length,
      l = 0,
      r = 0;
  while(l < lLen && r < rLen){
     if(left[l].points < right[r].points){
       result.push(left[l++]);
     }
     else{
       result.push(right[r++]);
    }
  }  
  //remaining part needs to be addred to the result
  return result.concat(left.slice(l)).concat(right.slice(r));
}
```

invoking gives me the expected result:

```
let rankArr = mergeSort(Teams).reverse();
console.log(rankArr);
//outputs:

[ { teamNum: 4, points: 5, GD: 4, goals: 5, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 3, points: 4, GD: 1, goals: 4, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 5, points: 4, GD: 2, goals: 6, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 0, points: 2, GD: -2, goals: 3, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 1, points: 2, GD: -2, goals: 3, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 2, points: 1, GD: -3, goals: 2, rank: 0 } ]
```

```js
const Teams = [ { teamNum: 0, points: 2, GD: -2, goals: 3, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 1, points: 2, GD: -2, goals: 3, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 2, points: 1, GD: -3, goals: 2, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 3, points: 4, GD: 1, goals: 4, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 4, points: 5, GD: 4, goals: 5, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 5, points: 4, GD: 2, goals: 6, rank: 0 } ]
  
function mergeSort(arr) {
  var len = arr.length;
  if (len < 2)
    return arr;
  var mid = Math.floor(len / 2),
    left = arr.slice(0, mid),
    right = arr.slice(mid);
  //send left and right to the mergeSort to break it down into pieces
  //then merge those
  return merge(mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right));
}


function merge(left, right) {
  var result = [],
    lLen = left.length,
    rLen = right.length,
    l = 0,
    r = 0;
  while (l < lLen && r < rLen) {
    if (left[l].points < right[r].points) {
      result.push(left[l++]);
    } else {
      result.push(right[r++]);
    }
  }
  //remaining part needs to be addred to the result
  return result.concat(left.slice(l)).concat(right.slice(r));
}
let rankArr = mergeSort(Teams).reverse();
console.log(rankArr);
```

Here's the mergeSort with a dynamic property

```
  function mergeSort(arr, prop){
   var len = arr.length;
   if(len <2)
      return arr;
   var mid = Math.floor(len/2),
       left = arr.slice(0,mid),
       right =arr.slice(mid);
   //send left and right to the mergeSort to break it down into pieces
   //then merge those
   return merge(mergeSort(left),mergeSort(right), prop);
}


function merge(left, right, prop){
  var result = [],
      lLen = left.length,
      rLen = right.length,
      l = 0,
      r = 0;
  while(l < lLen && r < rLen){
     if(left[l][prop] < right[r][prop]){
       result.push(left[l++]);
     }
     else{
       result.push(right[r++]);
    }
  }  
  //remaining part needs to be addred to the result
  return result.concat(left.slice(l)).concat(right.slice(r));
}

//invoked
  let rankArr = mergeSort(Teams,"points").reverse();
```

Outputs:

```
[ { teamNum: 3, points: 4, GD: 1, goals: 4, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 4, points: 5, GD: 4, goals: 5, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 5, points: 4, GD: 2, goals: 6, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 0, points: 2, GD: -2, goals: 3, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 1, points: 2, GD: -2, goals: 3, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 2, points: 1, GD: -3, goals: 2, rank: 0 } ]
```

```js
const Teams = [ { teamNum: 0, points: 2, GD: -2, goals: 3, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 1, points: 2, GD: -2, goals: 3, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 2, points: 1, GD: -3, goals: 2, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 3, points: 4, GD: 1, goals: 4, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 4, points: 5, GD: 4, goals: 5, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 5, points: 4, GD: 2, goals: 6, rank: 0 } ]
  
function mergeSort(arr, prop) {
  var len = arr.length;
  if (len < 2)
    return arr;
  var mid = Math.floor(len / 2),
    left = arr.slice(0, mid),
    right = arr.slice(mid);
  //send left and right to the mergeSort to break it down into pieces
  //then merge those
  return merge(mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right), prop);
}


function merge(left, right, prop) {
  var result = [],
    lLen = left.length,
    rLen = right.length,
    l = 0,
    r = 0;
  while (l < lLen && r < rLen) {
    if (left[l][prop] < right[r][prop]) {
      result.push(left[l++]);
    } else {
      result.push(right[r++]);
    }
  }
  //remaining part needs to be addred to the result
  return result.concat(left.slice(l)).concat(right.slice(r));
}

//invoked
console.log(mergeSort(Teams, "points").reverse());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dynamic `mergeSort` requires a second argument, the `prop`. When initially invoking it, the argument gets passed properly:

```
let rankArr = mergeSort(Teams,"points").reverse();
```

But you also need to pass it down to the recursive call. Change

```
return merge(mergeSort(left),mergeSort(right), prop);
```

to

```
return merge(mergeSort(left, prop),mergeSort(right, prop), prop);
```

otherwise, during recursion, it'll be `undefined`, and no sensible sorting will occur.

```js
const Teams = [ { teamNum: 0, points: 2, GD: -2, goals: 3, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 1, points: 2, GD: -2, goals: 3, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 2, points: 1, GD: -3, goals: 2, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 3, points: 4, GD: 1, goals: 4, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 4, points: 5, GD: 4, goals: 5, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 5, points: 4, GD: 2, goals: 6, rank: 0 } ];

function mergeSort(arr, prop){
   var len = arr.length;
   if(len <2)
      return arr;
   var mid = Math.floor(len/2),
       left = arr.slice(0,mid),
       right =arr.slice(mid);
   //send left and right to the mergeSort to break it down into pieces
   //then merge those
   return merge(mergeSort(left, prop),mergeSort(right, prop), prop);
}


function merge(left, right, prop){
  var result = [],
      lLen = left.length,
      rLen = right.length,
      l = 0,
      r = 0;
  while(l < lLen && r < rLen){
     if(left[l][prop] < right[r][prop]){
       result.push(left[l++]);
     }
     else{
       result.push(right[r++]);
    }
  }  
  //remaining part needs to be addred to the result
  return result.concat(left.slice(l)).concat(right.slice(r));
}

//invoked
  let rankArr = mergeSort(Teams,"points").reverse();
  console.log(rankArr);
```

Comment: Thank you! I had remembered to invoke with the property (at the bottom of the dynamic version), but I had missed passing it to the recursive call in the function (with left and right).

Answer (score 0):

You could just do:

```js
var arrayOfObjs = [ { teamNum: 0, points: 2, GD: -2, goals: 3, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 1, points: 2, GD: -2, goals: 3, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 2, points: 1, GD: -3, goals: 2, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 3, points: 4, GD: 1, goals: 4, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 4, points: 5, GD: 4, goals: 5, rank: 0 },
  { teamNum: 5, points: 4, GD: 2, goals: 6, rank: 0 } ];
var sorted = arrayOfObjs.slice();
sorted.sort(function(a, b){
  return b.points-a.points;
});
console.log(sorted);
```